# Path Integral Formalism and Two-Point Function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, greens-functions, sigma-models

I'm given an action,
$$A[\vec{S}] = \frac{\Theta}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \left(\frac{d\vec{S}}{dt}\right)^2, \tag{1}$$
with $$\vec{S}^2 = 1.\tag{2}$$ I'm asked to calculate the two point function,
$$ \int \mathcal{D}\vec{S} S_i(t) S_j(0) \exp\left(iA[\vec{S}]/\hbar\right).\tag{3}$$
This, I suppose, is the $O(3)$ model in $0+1$ dimensions.

**My attempt**:
The transition amplitude is easy(?) to calculate. One can rewrite the argument in $\exp$ using integration parts. Then this reduces to performing a Gaussian integral with the path integral being proportional to $\text{det}\left(-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\right)$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. My idea is to use the generating functional somehow to arrive at the two-point function. I was unable to find any resources to cross-check my methods, either.

Any short/long calculations are very much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Don't forget the constraint (2).

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for your reply. In my attempt, the only place where I used that was when using integration by parts (boundary terms vanish due to this condition). I did go through with the calculation and ended up with something that looks like photon propagator in $\xi = 1$ gauge. But, I'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{HINT:}$ The full path integral is

$$ \mathcal{Z} = \int \mathcal{D}\vec{S} \delta[\vec{S}\cdot \vec{S} -1] e^{i\int \mathcal{L}[\vec{S}]dt}$$

You can write the delta function using an auxiliary field as follows:

$$ \delta[\vec{S}\cdot \vec{S} -1] = \int \mathcal{D}\lambda e^{i\int \lambda(\vec{S}\cdot \vec{S} -1)dt}$$

Therefore the partition function tantamounts to calculating the integral over $\vec{S}$ and $\lambda$. The integral over S can be easily calculated as the integral is gaussian but it is not so easy to compute the $\lambda$ integral. The constraint allows non-trivial interaction to occur. Furthermore, you can also calculate the two point function.

There is also another way to write this partition function which is more suited to performing RG computation. You can read more about this in Kardar's Statistical Physics of Fields section 8.1 (Non-linear sigma model).